# Winform MenuStrip will not change from default color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, .net-4.5

In my application, I've been trying to change the background color of the `MenuStrip`, but nothing seems to work. I've tried to change its background just like changing the other component's background using the design's property window, but when I run my program, no change happens. Is this option broken?

Comment: If you mean the `MenuStrip.BackColor`, it works fine for me. The menu strip which is docked at Top in the form client region has `BackColor` affected OK with change to `MenuStrip.BackColor`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a ToolStripRenderer, have a look at the MenuStrip.Renderer property.